# uniform or dominated convergence of sequence of functions which are bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n\to f$ on $[0,1]$, where $f_n$ and $f$ be continuous with $f_n$ bounded. Then, which of the following are true:

1) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{[0,1]}f_n=\int_{[0,1]}f$

2)$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}|f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\to0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,1]}f_n=\int_{[0,1]}f$?

I think the first should be true by dominated convergence, since $f_n$ are bounded and $f$ is continuous. Any counterexamples? I have no idea about second one. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Since $f_n$'s and $f$ are continuous they are Reimann integrable and because of their definition on a compact set we can argue the convergence as uniform convergence. So the 2nd one is also true!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$For the first proposition, take$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
nπ \sin(nπx); &\displaystyle 0 \le x \le \frac{1}{n}\\
0; &\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} < x \le 1
\end{cases},
$$
and $f = 0$. Since $f_n(0) = 0 \ (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+)$, then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(0) = 0 = f(0)$. And if $0 < x \leqslant 1$, for $\displaystyle n > \frac{1}{x}$, there is $f_n(x) = 0$, thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 0 = f(0)$. So $f_n \to f$. However,\begin{gather*}
\int_0^1 f_n(x) \,\d x = \int_0^π \sin u \,\d u = 2, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_+\\
\int_0^1 f(x) \,\d x = 0,
\end{gather*}
thus$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) \,\d x = 2 \neq 0 = \int_0^1 f(x) \,\d x.
$$

For the second proposition, because\begin{align*}
\varlimsup_{n \to \infty} \left| \int_0^1 f_n(x) \,\d x - \int_0^1 f(x) \,\d x \right| \leqslant  \int_0^1 |f_n(x) - f(x)| \,\d x  = 0,
\end{align*}
then$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \int_0^1 f_n(x) \,\d x - \int_0^1 f(x) \,\d x \right| = 0,
$$
which implies$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x) \,\d x = \int_0^1 f(x) \,\d x.
$$